# No error but not working, run function when text changes Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

If the mywidget entry changes it should run the function `atado_enter`. If i put some error into this function, it gives me error msg, but if i want to do something it strictly do nothing. Can someone explain me whats wrong with it?

```
#!usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import time
import mysql.connector
import getpass
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
global atado_kartya_szam
global atvevo_kartya_szam
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
#from Tkinter import Tk, Text, TOP, BOTH, X, N, LEFT
from Tkinter import * 
from Tkinter import Tk as tk
from ttk import Frame, Style, Entry, Label

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):     
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)        
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        def atado_enter(*args): 
            print("vmi")

        self.parent.title("Pozi")
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand=True)

        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(fill=X)

        lbl1 = Label(frame1, text = "ĂtadĂł kĂˇrtyĂˇja", width = 15)
        lbl1.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, expand=True)

        myvar = StringVar()
        myvar.set('')
        mywidget = Entry(frame1,textvariable=myvar,width=10)
        mywidget.pack()
        myvar.trace('w',atado_enter)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("550x450+300+300") # width x heigth + x + y (on screen)
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I realize you already have your answer but I wanted to offer a different approach. I have modified my answer if you care to take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once `initUI` completes executing, `myvar` gets garbage collected because there are no more living references to it. A StringVar that gets garbage collected will not trigger any callbacks.

Try keeping a longer-lived reference to the object. The easiest way to do this is to assign it to an attribute of `self`:

```
    #... rest of function goes here...
    myvar = StringVar()
    myvar.set('')
    mywidget = Entry(frame1,textvariable=myvar,width=10)
    mywidget.pack()
    myvar.trace('w',atado_enter)
    self.myvar = myvar
```

Comment: Can you explain me what does self do exactly?

Comment: `self` is a reference to the `Example` object that is being initialized by `initUI`. Assigning `myvar` to its `myvar` attribute will cause `myvar` to live at least as long as the Example object is alive. This is sufficient for our needs; if the Example object is dead, then the window isn't visible to the user any more, so we don't need `myvar` after that.

Comment: @Kevin I have made some changes to my answer to be more in line with the OPs needs. I realize you have already answered the question with the correct use of `trace` so I wanted to provide a possible alternative if you care to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

First. I think you have an issue with your tkinter imports.

Change this:

```
from Tkinter import * 
from Tkinter import Tk as tk
from ttk import Frame, Style, Entry, Label
```

To this:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

Seeing that there was already an answer using `trace` and my answer was lacking, I decided to add an interesting alternative by checking ever 200 milliseconds to see if the value has changed. This number can be changed to any ms. It might not be as simple as trace but it does work.

I removed the trace and created a function/method that will check if `mywidget` has changed and if true then call `atado_entry`.

```
last_mywidget = [""]
def CheckMywidget():
    if last_mywidget != [mywidget.get()]:
        atado_enter(mywidget.get())
        last_mywidget[0] = mywidget.get()
        print(last_mywidget)
        mywidget.after(200, CheckMywidget)
    else:
        mywidget.after(200, CheckMywidget)
CheckMywidget()
```

Here is the complete code:

```
class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):     
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)        
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        def atado_enter(*args): 
            print("vmi")

        self.parent.title("Pozi")
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand=True)

        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(fill=X)

        lbl1 = Label(frame1, text = "ĂtadĂł kĂˇrtyĂˇja", width = 15)
        lbl1.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, expand=True)

        myvar = StringVar()
        myvar.set('')
        mywidget = Entry(frame1,textvariable=myvar,width=10)
        mywidget.pack()
        #myvar.trace("w", atado_enter)
        self.myvar = myvar

        last_mywidget = [""]
        def CheckMywidget():
            if last_mywidget != [mywidget.get()]:
                atado_enter(mywidget.get())
                last_mywidget[0] = mywidget.get()
                mywidget.after(200, CheckMywidget)
            else:
                mywidget.after(200, CheckMywidget)
        CheckMywidget()

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("550x450+300+300") # width x heigth + x + y (on screen)
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I agree that the imports could stand to be cleaned up, but I don't think it's the cause of the problem. Even implementing these changes, when I type text into the entry box, the `atado_enter` function doesn't execute.

Comment: @Kevin I made an update to my answer. I think you are trying to call a function once you hit enter in the entry box.

Comment: The OP is using a variable trace, not a bind. Plus, the OP seems to explicitly want to use the ttk `Entry` rather than the Tkinter `Entry`.

Comment: Oh. I was unaware that ttk entry was different from tkinter entry. I guess I need to do some reading.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I changed my answer to provide a possible different approach. Seeing that I could not just simply correct my answer as there is already a good accepted answer for trace I decided to at least provide a different option. Would you consider this acceptable?

Comment: Personally, I would not consider a method that polls the widget every 200 seconds acceptable. It's less efficient, requires more code, and won't scale particularly well. The question wasn't "how do I call a function when the value changes?", it was "why doesn't this trace work?". Answering "why doesn't trace work?" with "don't use trace" isn't very useful.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: True. I decided to provide an alternative because a valid answer was already selected and my original answer was not helpful. I guess I could just delete my answer all together.